# Vue / Laravel - SPA performance

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I noticed that while using a REST client like insomnia, I'm getting a high ms while performing a `post` for login.

[image]

Also my **app.js** is currently sitting at 2.43 MB with just these lines.

```
window.Vue = require('vue')

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import NProgress from 'vue-nprogress'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

import App from './App.vue'
import { router } from './routes.js'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(NProgress)

Vue.component('base-table', require('./components/BaseTable.vue').default)

const vuetify = new Vuetify();
const nprogress = new NProgress();

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h=>h(App),
  vuetify,
  router,
  nprogress
});
```

I'm fairly new with Vue + Laravel SPA and I don't know if this is considered as very bad for loading an application. Will minimizer greatly reduce the file size and boost loading speed when it's ready for production?

Comment: your app.js  includes all library which you  have imported that's why it's 2.43 MB and app.js is entry point it will load only 1st time . and if u really care about speed then i suggest you to look for any server side rendering option

Comment: You're right. But is it normal to have this kind of file size? Sorry I'm learning in a step by step manner. Thank you very much for that advise.

Comment: yes it is normal always use production build so that u will get compressed file

Comment: You can use [async components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) to only load certain parts of your vue application when needed. for my own project, I split all pages from the main bundle like this.

Comment: For your post request: there isn't much we can do without knowing what your back-end code looks like or what your server configuration is.

Comment: Vuetify is quite big but [if setup correctly](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte) it can tree-shake and include only the components used...